# Material stepper - Steps disappear when using a array of formgroup

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using the stepper of `@angular/material` and I have some behavior I cannot completely explain. I'm using a array where a formgroup is put in. This array is my source for the `ngFor` and I pass the item to the step. When I remove one item from the array the `mat-step's` are gone. But the list is still filled with items.

Using a trackyby didn't help btw. The only thing that helps is to select a different step before changing the state.  *(see line 51)*

Scenario:

1. Fill in the form
2. Click on add one item
3. Fill in the form
4. Press remove one item
5. See the steps disappear

[Example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stepper-with-list-of-formgroup)

**Question**: Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to `this.selectedIndex`. Because after splice there is no item with the selectedIndex. So you can change the removeone function as below.

```
  public removeone() {
    console.error('remove: ', this.selectedIndex)
    /** REMOVE THE LINE BELOW TO LET THE STEPS STAY ON THE SCREEN */
    // this.stepper._steps.first.select();
    var  selected = this.selectedIndex;
    this.stepper._stateChanged();
    this.change.detectChanges();
    this.stepper.previous();
    this._list.splice(selected, 1);
  }
```